# Replacemet of a variable in shell script from another file - preferably python

Tags: bash, python-2.7, shell

My shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
.....
a='30'  
b='2'  
c='0.9'
.....
```

Is there a way to replace the values of my variables using python script/any other language? I should be able to replace the values with multiple values also. For example, I should be able to set b = '2 1 3' and a = '0.9 0.8' ..

Comment: What do you mean under 'replace'? Like having a Python script edit your shell script, or your shell script pulling the variable values from the Python script?

Comment: Python script edit my shell script values

Answer (score 1):

It's simple: add a line to the top of your Bash script:

```
source thevars.sh
```

Then you can write all the variable assignments you require using a trivial Python script to create `thevars.sh`.

The Bash script can be modified slightly to have default arguments in case `thevars.sh` does not exist:

```
test -f thevars.sh && source thevars.sh

a=${a-30}
b=${b-2  
c=${c-0.9}
```

Then if `thevars.sh` has any variables assigned, they will be used instead of the defaults--for example:

```
a="foo bar"
b=9001
```

Comment: You can also call the script with a precommand modifier like `a=50 ./script.sh`; note that a definition inside `thevars.sh` would override such an assignment.